# How to retry other request in specific pipeline when connection false

Tags: scrapy

> [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying http://img14.360buyimg.com/n1/s800x800_jfs/t21448/27/2565333063/465767/c06c0af6/5b5c83e6Nb83e3a19.pn > (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://img14.360buyimg.com/n1/s800x800_jfs/t21448/27/2565333063/465767/c06c0af6/5b5c83e6Nb83e3a19.png took longer than 180.0 seconds..

Like This . I have several pipelines and I want to request other image url when request timeout failure.

I saw scrapy

> Retry Middleware

But It seems like for all requests. I want to Specify Only My ImagePipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the [RetryMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry).

The setting `RETRY_ENABLED` is `True` by default, you can change it to `False` to disable the middleware.